# How to customize nginx configuration in AWS beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker multi container application deployed in AWS beanstalk, each container using a different port.

Let's say my domain is www.example.com, so what I need to do is that requests made to www.example.com/api are routed to the port 3000, and the requests made to www.example.com/admin are routed to port 5000. I think I can configure nginx to achieve that, but I don't know how to do it.

Here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html it says that I can extend nginx configuration in beanstalk, by creating a .conf file, but I don't know what should be the content of such file.

Comment: Do you use ALB? You can specify all these routes at the ALB level.

Comment: I am not using Application load balancer, because as long as I know, I'd need to pay for that, and I have a very limited budget